# how to retrieve value from specific columns of excel using spring rest

Tags: java, spring

Below is my controller code and service code. The service code is returning only the last value of the map, though I am adding it in the for loop. Not sure what I missing. Also in the postman, I am not getting any response, just the success code as 200. At least I should be getting the last value. The expected output is the following:

```
    "testCaseId": "TA_SCEN01",
    "testCaseDescription" : some test
    "executionStatus": "Yes",
    "executionBrowser": "Chrome"
```

Please excuse me for the long desciption of the problem statement. I just tried to give as much info for better understanding.

the controller code is below

```
@RestController
public class ExcelController {

    @Autowired
    ExcelService service;
@GetMapping(value="/{excelSheetName}/{sheetName}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>> getExcelDetails(@PathVariable("excelSheetName") String excelSheetName, @PathVariable("sheetName") String sheetName) {
        service.getExcelDetails(excelSheetName, sheetName);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, String>>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The service code is below

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getExcelDetails(String excelSheetName, String sheetName) {
    //Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    //List list = new LinkedList<Object>();
    List list = new LinkedList<Object>();
    String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\140117\\Desktop\\NSARF\\Successfactor_TalentAcquisition_TestCase.xls";
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        HSSFWorkbook workSheet = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workSheet.getSheetAt(0);
        ExcelDetail excelObj = new ExcelDetail();
        String testId = "testCaseId";
        String testDesc = "testCaseDescription";
        String status = "executionStatus";
        String browser = "executionBrowser";
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
             Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
            //Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            Cell tcId = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0);
            Cell desc = sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(1);
            Cell execStatus = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(2);
            Cell execBrowser = sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(5);
            if(null != tcId || null != desc || execStatus != null || execBrowser != null) {
            map.put(testId, tcId.toString());
            map.put(testDesc, desc.toString());
            map.put(status, execStatus.toString());
            map.put(browser, execBrowser.toString());
            list.add(map);
            }else {
                break;
            }
            //list.add(map);
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        //list.add(map);
        System.out.println(list);

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure it makes any difference, but why you declared List list = new LinkedList<Object>(); instead of List<Map<String,String>> list = new LinkedList<>() ?

Comment: i m just specifying the type by using Object